# Change rectangle dimensions: Change vertices in FloatBuffer or use glScalef

Tags: java, android, performance, opengl-es

So it goes like this. I have 40 rectangles of different heights. 20 placed at the top edge of the screen linearly one after the other and the other 20 placed at the bottom edge, also linearly.

[image: Screenshot]

The camera is moving to the right. As soon as a rectangle is outside the camera's view, it's height is changed and it is moved to the extreme right.

So to change the height, if I change the floats in the FloatBuffer, then I need to do it for just two rectangles in one frame but if I use glScalef I'll have to do it for all 40.

It seems to me that the first method is the more efficient way to go but then I remember reading somewhere that FloatBuffer.put() is expensive and also that scaling 100 times a frame isn't much of a big deal.

But since I'm a newbie I'm all confused about which should be the better thing to do in terms of performance.

Comment: Is there one `FloatBuffer` per rectangle or are they packed together in one? Are you using VBOs?

Comment: @StefanHanke At the time of posting, I was using a separate FloatBuffer for each rectangle. Now I'm using only one FloatBuffer whose contents I'm changing each frame.
And I'm not using VBOs.
Oh, and sorry about the delay. I thought nobody replied. Didn't notice the notification either.